# Date formats being passed into SQL SPROC via C# MVC web app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a method

```
 public Data<DTO.Appointment> Search(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        Data<DTO.Appointment> data = new Data<DTO.Appointment>();
        try
        {
            using (SearchResultReader r = new SearchResultReader("db", "sproc_name"))
            {
                r.AddParameter("@StartDate", startDate);
                r.AddParameter("@EndDate", endDate);
                data.Data = r.GetValues();
                data.SetSucceeded(data.Data.Count);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            data.SetFailed(ex.Message);
        }
        return data;

    }
```

> The two paramters on debug are Start Date = 14/01/2020 00:00:00 and End Date = 14/01/2020 23:59:59

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC [APP].[SPROC-NAME]
@StartDate DATETIME,
@EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @True BIT = 1;
DECLARE @False BIT = 0;

DECLARE @Today DATETIME;
SET @Today = GETDATE();

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Appointment op WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.IdMap pim ON pim.SourceId = op.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Person p WITH(NOLOCK) ON pim.Id = p.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.test cons WITH(NOLOCK) ON cons.Code = op.Code 
WHERE 
((@StartDate IS NULL) OR (cast(StartDateTime as date) >= cast(@StartDate as date)))
AND ((@EndDate IS NULL) OR (cast(StartDateTime as date) <= cast(@EndDate as date)))

END
```

The problem i am having is that in the application it is bringing results back for the day after the specified date range but if i run the sproc it brings back only dates within the date range?

I have had this issue before and solved it by casting the dates in the where clause as "DATES" but it is  not working this time.

Maybe SQL is formatting the date supplied by the application weirdly?

Ta.

Comment: Dates have no formats, they are binary values. Any problems you have are not due to any kind of formatting. If you only want to use the date part, change the parameter types to `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos H, thanks for your reply, I have tried this but with no luck. Thanks

Comment: @madreflection Could this be a reason for it displaying results from outside the daterange, it usually shows tomorrows appointments aswell.

Comment: Tried *what* with no luck? Using `date` will clean up the query. What does your data look like? The problem is caused because the way the query is written, some unexpected values match that condition. We can't guess what those values are.

Comment: @S.Gray btw using `NOLOCK` takes *extra* locks and can return bad data. It won't make a bad query run faster.

Comment: Check if any part in your chain isn't assuming the `datetime` instances have to be adjusted for time zones, which could easily cause them to slip a few hours. (SQL Server doesn't do this.) Also, it is bad practice in general to define date/time ranges as "just before the end" due to the precision of `DATETIME` and missing a second of data even in the best case; use "just after the end" (2020-01-15) and `<` comparisons.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If i search for example with the paramters being startdate = 15/01/2020 00:00:00 and enddate being 15/01/2020 23:59:59 it brings back any row back with a startdatetime on the 15th however it also brings back results with start date times like the following 16/01/2020 11:45:00 and 16/01/2020 12:00:00

Comment: @S.Gray don't describe a single value, post the actual data. Jeroen's comment is important - if your code runs on eg GMT+1 but the server is on GMT, the casts on the server will produce *different* dates after 11pm.

Comment: @madreflection unless the client and server timezones differ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately this query requires (NOLOCK)

Comment: @S.Gray no it doesn't. No query does. `NOLOCK` means there are serious bugs that were covered up

Comment: If all else fails, you can of course just use Profiler to see what command is *actually* issued to SQL Server. (Even though Profiler also performs a formatting step to present the binary `DATETIME` values as if they were string literals -- but at least it won't do anything with time zones, so that's fairly reliable.)

Comment: @madreflection and then the query goes and discards that `23:59`. Without the actual data we can waste quite a bit of time trying to guess combinations that cause this to fail. Knowing there are already serious issues covered up by `NOLOCK`. Perhaps the OP added that because the tables are busy, thus extra vulnerable to the very data movement problems caused by NOLOCK

Comment: @madreflection we weren't given *any* of the table data. We have no idea which were the invalid rows included in the question

Comment: @madreflection it's not a 0-second range, it's a 24-hour range due to the `cast( field as date)` clauses. These convert the equality into a range comparison. This should behave the same as `cast(StartDateTime as date)>='20200114' AND cast(StartDateTime as date)<='20200114'` or just `cast(StartDateTime as date)='20200114'` and return every record in that day

Comment: Thanks All, getting rid of the casts in the sql seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

Please cast @StartDate & @EndDate to DateTime & not just Date